# Unexpected Ruby Regexp behaviour

Tags: ruby, regex, string

Given the following string, `str`:

```
\begin{align*}
\intertext{Here is some text}
x^{2}+2x+3=2\\
\intertext{Here is some more}
\end{align*}
```

I would like to move the intertext strings outside of the align environment, like so:

```
Here is some text
\begin{align*}
x^{2}+2x+3=2\\
\end{align*}
Here is some more
```

Note that I only want to do this when intertext appears immediately before or after a \begin{something} or an \end{something}. With this in mind, I wrote the following Regexps:

```
begin_align = /\\begin\{([^}]*)\}\n\\intertext\{([^}]*)\}/m
end_align = /\\intertext\{([^}]*)\}\n\\end\{([^}]*)\}/m
```

Because of the grouped elements in brackets, when I call `m = str.match(begin_align)`, I can grab `m[0]` (the matched string), `m[1]` (which should be the given environment, `align*` in this example), and `m[2]`, which should be the text inside intertext. If I write `str.match(m[0])` I get `nil`. Why?

I found a way around this: If I instead call `str.match(Regexp.quote(m[0]))`, I get a match. *However*, if I then try to replace this match with `str.sub(Regexp.quote(m[0]),'')`, say, nothing happens. If instead I write `str.sub(m[0],'')`, I get the expected result. How come?

While I was trying to debug this example, I noticed something else that I can't understand. If I write 
`"\\begin{align".match("\\begin{align")`,
I get no match despite them being identical strings. If I 'escape' the second `\\` as:
`"\\begin{align".match("\\\\begin{align")`,
then I get a match. If I *then* try to put the asterisk
`"\\begin{align*".match("\\\\begin{align*")`,
I get `#<MatchData "\\begin{align">`: it ignores the asterisk. I have to escape the second asterisk with `\\*`. What's going on?

Comment: You should escape any special character in a regex context if you want to match it literally. i.e. `*` should be escaped or used in a character class `[*]` or check `"\\begin{align".match("\\\\begin{align")`

Comment: @revo In the example `str.match(Regexp.quote(m[0]))`, the string `m[0]` contains unescaped special regex characters and matches correctly, while it doesn't in the following example `str.sub(Regexp.quote(m[0]),'')`. Ditto for the examples at the end (`{` is a regex metacharacter, after all). Clearly something is happening in the internal conversion to Regex - that's what I'm asking about.

Comment: Show me how you initialize `str`.

Comment: `str = "\\begin{align*}\n\\intertext{Here is some text}\nx^{2}+2x+3=2\\\\\n\\intertext{Here is some more}\n\\end{align*}"`

Comment: @DanielLittlewood The last `match` example--they're the same string, but you don't match against strings, you match against regexes. The string is converted to a regex, where there are special chars. You'd need `"\\begin{align".match("\\\\begin{align")` to match.

Comment: @DaveNewton That's what I suspect - but what exactly is it doing? `"\\begin{align"` is not a regular expression, so it has to be converted to one. Even if you make the jump to say "Regex metacharacters in the string, which behave as literals, should be converted to Regex metacharacters in the Regex, rather than literals", why does `\\ ` need to be escaped while `{` does not?

Comment: @DaveNewton Just spotted that my second line (which matches) didn't have four `\\`s, that's fixed.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood I don't know the precise reason, but I'd assume since it's not a complete or valid quantifier, it assumes it's just a curly brace. You *may* escape it, and when working with strings-that-are-meant-to-be-regexes you're probably best off using `%r` anyway.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood Did you find the below answer helpful? I can improve or remove it if it doesn't fit your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`m[0]`:

```
\\begin{align*}\n\\intertext{Here is some text}
```

[Note on](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/sub) `.sub()`:

> The *pattern* is typically a `Regexp`; if given as a `String`, any
>   regular expression metacharacters it contains will be interpreted
>   literally.

So `m[0]` contains `*` which is a quantifier. Given as `'*'` to `.sub()` it means nothing but a literal `*` character. But given to `.match()` as `'*'` it is interpreted as a quantifier and the reason for `str.match('*')` to throw an error. `align*` in a regex context means string `alig` preceding any number of `n` characters.

So for `.match()` to work you have to care about such special characters but for `.sub()` it is just a mess to use `Regexp.quote` and pass it as a string.